# Voyager 1's Inclusion of Quranic verse for Extraterrestrial Aliens

Tags: quran, science

Voyager 1 by NASA includes an audio recording featuring a recitation of a Quranic verse, specifically Quran 55:33 from Surah ar-Rahman. This recitation can be accessed at the "United Nations Greetings / Whale Songs" Section of Voyager Golden Record .

https://goldenrecord.org/#discus-aureus

The verse is recited in Arabic:

يَـٰمَعْشَرَ ٱلْجِنِّ وَٱلْإِنسِ إِنِ ٱسْتَطَعْتُمْ أَن تَنفُذُوا۟ مِنْ أَقْطَارِ ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٰتِ وَٱلْأَرْضِ فَٱنفُذُوا۟ ۚ لَا تَنفُذُونَ إِلَّا بِسُلْطَـٰنٍ

The translation of the Quran verse sent in Voyager 1 is as follows:

"O genera of Jinn and mankind, If you are able to penetrate beyond the realms of the heavens and the earth, then penetrate. You cannot penetrate without power."

https://quran.com/ar-rahman/33?translations=84

The Transliteration of the Quran verse sent in Voyager 1 is as follows:

Yaa ma’sharal jinni wal insi inis tata’tum an tanfuzoo min aqtaaris samaawaati wal ardi fanfuzoo; laa tanfuzoona illaa bisultaan.

https://quran411.com/surah-ar-rahman

This recitation can be accessed at the 5 minutes and 15 seconds mark in the provided audio source, available Here.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cEzcFXRKHUw&t=310s

[image]

- 

Is it True ?